# Mongoose doesn't returns fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We have NodeJs backend application which interacts with mongo database.
I have strict schema for retrieve the objects.
NodeJs application uses `module.export` technology.

I use follow dependencies:

```
"mongoose": "^4.7.8",
"promise": "^8.0.1",
```

I have follow schema:

account.js

```
const   mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        ColumnModel = require('./column');

var AccountModel = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "ID is required"],
        unique: true
    },
    maxAvailableDate: {
        type: Date,
        require: [true, "maxAvailableDate is required"]
    },
    types: {
        type: [String],
        required: [true, "Log types are required"]
    },
    metaInfo: {
        conversion: {
            type: [ColumnModel],
            required: [true, "Conversion columns are required"]
        },
        impression: {
            type: [ColumnModel],
            required: [true, "Impression columns are required"]
        },
        clickevent: {
            type: [ColumnModel],
            required: [true, "Clickevent columns are required"]
        }
    }
});
```

column.js

```
const   mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = new mongoose.Schema({
    columnName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    columnType: {
        type: String,
        enum: [
            "string", 
            "date",
            "int",
            "real"
        ],
        required: true
    }
});
```

Then I use the model:

```
const AccountModel = require('./account'),
      mongoose = require('mongoose');

let AccountModel = mongoose.model('Account', AccountModel);

AccountModel.findOne(
    {id: accountId},
    (err, result) => {
        let types = result.types;
        console.log(result);
    }
);
```

I get follow in output:

```
{ _id: 5a98116ff7f1e223e5b291fa,
  id: 119,
  maxAvailableDate: 2018-03-01T14:42:55.262Z,
  types: [ 'impression', 'conversion', 'clickevent' ],
  metaInfo: 
   { conversion: 
      [ [Object],
        [Object] ],
     impression: 
      [ [Object],
        [Object] ],
     clickevent: 
      [ [Object],
        [Object] ] } }
```

BUT `types` IS UNDEFINED!!!
I know that I can combine `lean()` with `Query`, but I need mutable oject, not just the raw data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I didn't `module.export` in accounts.js

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `toObject` method in order to access the fields.

Example:

```
var data = result.toObject();
console.log(data.types); // "[ 'impression', 'conversion', 'clickevent' ]"
```

reference:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toObject